# Why do I get the errre 'nonconformable argument' in multilinear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to find the leverage between predictor variables & model attempting to identify extrapolation.

Here is my problem. Among these predictions, which one is extrapolation? And why?

- Predictions: Using the fitted regression in previous question, obtain the prediction of the response variable for a new player with Age = 35, AverageDrive = 287, DrivingAccuracy = 64, GreensonRegulation = 64.9, AverageNumofPutts = 1.778, SavePercent = 48, NumEvents = 26.

Here is model I am working with:

```
model1 <- step(lm(AverageWinnings ~ Age + AverageDrive + DrivingAccuracy +
                                    GreensonRegulation + AverageNumofPutts + 
                                    SavePercent + NumEvents, data=pga))
```

Here is the code he would like us to use on some level - Looking at 'min and max' of each variable is not sufficient. He wants us to find leverage to determine, which I get. But what is wrong here?

```
newx <- c(1, 35, 287, 64, 64.9, 1.778, 48, 26) #create a new vector
X <- model.matrix(model1) #create the design matrix
```

Then this line produces the error

```
lev <- t(newx) %*% solve(t(X) %*%X) %*% newx
```

> Error in t(newx) %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) : non-conformable arguments

Comment: It would help a lot if you took your pga dataframe, typed dput(pga) into your RStudio console, and then copied and pasted that output into your question, and formatted as code!

Comment: Since`X` is part of the arguments throwing the non-comformable error we would obviously need to know its dimensions.

Comment: I am so sorry for not responding! Good call - New to this community which is awesome. I had a colleague who is a master of R help me at the 11th hour. Thanks a ton